# Segmentation fault thrown when importing cudnn

Tags: lua, torch

I'm new to Lua and Torch7 but after successfully (it seems) installing the environment I keep getting segmentation error on line:

```
require 'cudnn'
```

I should also note that when I do

```
require 'cunn' or require 'torch'
```

I get no errors...

My system is 
CUDA 10.0
GPU: Tesla K80

Comment: I'd recommend running lua in gdb and checking what exactly triggers an error. It isn't easy to say what causes this problem.